# How to bind two columns into one so that each row is preserved?

Tags: r

I have merged table with nominees and the movies they have won the oscar and globe. The columns for movies are film.x and film.y for Oscar and Globe accordingly. I created the column film to create film list of all the movies that have won the awards. I managed to match movies from film.x to film as follows:

```
 if(!is.na(winners$film.x)) {
      winners$film = winners$film.x
    }
```

And it did work. Although I got a warning message: Warning message:

```
In if (!is.na(winners$film.x)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

But when I tried to do the same for film.y:

```
if(is.na(winners$film)) {
  winners$film = winners$y
}
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
winners$film[is.na(winners$film)] <- winners$film.y
```

But got an error:

```
In x[...] <- m :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I bet that there is really simple way to do this I am just not aware. I would like the columns film.x and film.y to just be one column with corresponding actors (nominees) to each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `coalesce` to get the first non-NA element in each row

```
library(dplyr)
winners2 <- winners %>%
              mutate_at(vars(film.x, film.y), as.character) %>%
              mutate(film = coalesce(film.x, film.y)) %>%
              select(-film.x, -film.y)
```

---

Or if we are using the `base R`, make sure the length of elements are same in both `lhs` and `rhs` of the `<-`

```
i1 <- is.na(winners$film)
winners$film[i1] <- winners$film.y[i1]
```

Comment: I applied your first method and got an error:
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(513L, 443L, 39L, 526L, 39L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: Now again I have another problem. I try to replace missing values within a column with a "TRUE" logical ( or anything really) and I am using your second method, the R doesn't pop an error but I still have NA in those places that I replaced with i1.

Comment: @user67 if you want to replace the missing values, yes, you can use that method.  the `coalesce` is for coalescing two columns having both/either NA elements and want to get non-NA column as the output.  Based on the order of arguments, the first non-NA is selected

Comment: @user67 That is possible only when the corresponding values of 'film.y' is NA.  Can you check `winners$film.y[i1]`

Comment: Now it's different table. I did join these two succesfully. But then I added new column --> winners$win <-- TRUE and then attached this table to the bigger one. Now every movie that hasn't won has an entry NA of the win column.

Comment: @user67 if you don't have a corresponding value based on merging, it would give NA for that.  Can you please post as a new question with `dput` of examples and expected output so that it is easier to understand

Comment: @user67 please don't turn it to `factor`.  It makes it complicate.  Your `i1` should be `i1 <- is.na(winners$win)` instead of `i1 <-- winners$win[is.na(winners$win)];` i.e. it should be logical vector